# How to save 2 NSMutableDictionary on disk

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The development is in Xcode for iOS. I used 2 separate NSmutabledictionary.

I DON´T want to add them (when searching I found that often, but that is not what I try to do)

The app has to store them on the disk and when the app launches it can read the dictionary.
It is not a custom class so `initWithCoder` and the other one is not necessary (is this right?)

```
NSArray *data = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [data objectAtIndex:0];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"location"];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:"Dictionary" toFile:path];
```

This works but when I want to save another dictionary it won't work. My first thought would be to change the objectAtIndex to 1. But Xcode gives me an error when I do that. When I only give another name it simply won't save, but Xcode don't give an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use NSUSerDefaults to save data on disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Find out where the documents folder is
NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
// Create the file path for a file named 'location' inside the documents folder
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"location"];

// Write an array containing both of your arrays to a file at that path
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:@[myFirstArray, mySecondArray] toFile:path];
```

Then, to read them back:

```
// Read back the array containing the two arrays
NSArray *arrays = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

// Get the individual arrays from the array
NSMutableArray *myFirstArray = arrays[0];
NSMutableArray *mySecondArray = arrays[1];
```